# You tube search list api videos does not exactly match search list in You Tube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have implemented YouTube search list API and I indicate this property in my request:

```
order: 'relevance'
```

But when I type 'cars' on my site and also 'cars' on YouTube I get different response. How to achieve same videos on my site like YouTube?

Example: If I search ships on my website I get 10 videos. If I do that in YouTube search I am supposed to get the same set of videos. But it differs!

How this is happening?

My code-->

```
 var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    q: q,
    maxResults: maxresults,
    part: 'snippet',
    order: 'relevance',
    // safeSearch: 'strict',
    type: 'video'

});
```

Comment: You should provide us more elements to help you

Comment: @XavM More elements?

Comment: Can it be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: let's see your code